# Max value for a Multi-key Hash

Tags: ruby

This is my Hash (in Json)
I need to get the Maximum value of each "high" value. For example, in this case is 16.94

How to get this in Ruby?

I tried with [].max function, but i don't know to set the "key" where valutate the max

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 124,
  "created": "2012-03-21T20:45:39Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "results": {
   "quote": [
    {
     "date": "2010-03-10",
     "Date": "2010-03-10",
     "Open": "16.51",
     "High": "16.94",
     "Low": "16.51",
     "Close": "16.79",
     "Volume": "33088600",
     "Adj_Close": "16.79"
    },
    {
     "date": "2010-03-09",
     "Date": "2010-03-09",
     "Open": "16.41",
     "High": "16.72",
     "Low": "16.40",
     "Close": "16.53",
     "Volume": "20755200",
     "Adj_Close": "16.53"
    },
    {
     "date": "2010-03-08",
     "Date": "2010-03-08",
     "Open": "16.32",
     "High": "16.61",
     "Low": "16.30",
     "Close": "16.52",
     "Volume": "30554000",
     "Adj_Close": "16.52"
    },
    {
     "date": "2010-03-05",
     "Date": "2010-03-05",
     "Open": "15.89",
     "High": "16.38",
     "Low": "15.89",
     "Close": "16.06",
     "Volume": "21415000",
     "Adj_Close": "16.06"
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `quotes` contains the array (after JSON parsing) that is the value of the `"quote"` key, you can use [`max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by):

```
quotes.max_by { |quote| quote["High"].to_f }["High"].to_f  #=> 16.94
```

Alternatively you could use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map) & [`max`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max):

```
quotes.map { |quote| quote["High"].to_f }.max
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'yajl'
data = Yajl::Parser.parse json
data["query"]["results"]["quote"].max_by{|q| q["High"].to_f}
#=> {"date"=>"2010-03-10",
 "Date"=>"2010-03-10",
 "Open"=>"16.51",
 "High"=>"16.94",
 "Low"=>"16.51",
 "Close"=>"16.79",
 "Volume"=>"33088600",
 "Adj_Close"=>"16.79"}
```

Comment: The one gotcha with your solution is the `to_i` could result in the wrong result due to integer rounding.